# Outbound SMTP email not being delivered, but still disappearing from the queue and pickup folder

Tags: smtp, email-server, windows-server-2012-r2, email-bounces

After setting up my smtp server on a Windows 2012 server r2 on port 587. I tested the email functions by creating a text file labeled email with the following code inside:

```
From:admin@mydomain.com
to:otheremail@gmail.com
Sunject: Test Email

This is the body

.
```

1. Then I saved the email.txt file.
2. Dropped it in the pickup folder inside mailroot.
3. After a few seconds the email.txt dissapeared from the pickup folder.
4. It appears in the queue folder
5. But then disspears from the queue folder

At this point I checked my gmail to see if it was delivered, but there was no mail. So I checked the badmail folder, and of course it was empty.

So my question is what is happening to my email? Is it being delivered? Do I have to make changes to the smtp server to get it to work? Is my email being blocked since it doesnt even show up in my spam folder?

**UPDATE 2:** Just checked the dropped folder and I've been receiving Delivery Status Notifications (failure) that says:

```
smtp; 550 5.1.0 Authentication required
```

What does that mean and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: AFAIK, you should be using the .eml extension with your test email, not the .txt extension.

Comment: I followed a tutorial that said. txt. Anyway I tried your method renaming it .msg, but it still gives me the same error. It disspears from the pick up folder and thge queue folder, but then it comes back in my drop folder as a failed delivery

Comment: I misspoke in my original comment. Try using the **.eml** extension.

Comment: Same problem. I get a receive a drop folder message stating failure to deliver message

Comment: What's the nature of the NDR? Can you post the text of it here?

Comment: Action failedStatus: 5.1.0 Diagnostic code:smtp;550 5.1.0 Authentication required

Answer (score 1):

I solved it! I just followed these steps.

1. Go to IIS 6.0 manager
2. Right click on your domain - Select properties
3. On the delivery tab choose outbound security
4. Select basic authentication
5. Type up your isp username in my case it was my comcast username and password
6. Check the box for TLS encryption and press Ok
7. Press Apply.

Now you should be able to send mail without the error 5.1.0

Comment: So you're relaying through your ISP? That information would have been useful had it been included in your question. At any rate, glad you got it resolved.

Comment: Yes, thank you anyway. I was only using it as a smart host, but I forgot to add the username and password along with the tls encryption.